# Вызвать метод RecyclerView адаптера в другом классе

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вызвать метод onItemClick(int position) адаптера
RecyclerView  в другом классе ну или хотябы за пределами адаптера ?

```
public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private String[] mData = new String[0];
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    // Data is passed into the constructor
    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, String[] data) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // Inflates the cell layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.z_maket_item_rv_gallery, parent, false);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    // Binds the data to the textview in each cell
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String animal = mData[position];

    }

    // Total number of cells
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.length;
    }

    // Stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView info_text; // количество изображений
        public TextView info_name_maps;// Номер карты
        public ImageView iv_image_map; // Изображение(первое с карты??)

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            info_text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_text);
            info_name_maps = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.info_name_maps);
            iv_image_map = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image_map);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    // Convenience method for getting data at click position
    public String getItem(int id) {
        return mData[id];
    }

    // Method that executes your code for the action received
    public void onItemClick(int position) {
      // ????????
    }
}
```

Comment: Через экземпляр адаптера, который нужно создать. Вам нужно лишь указать нужную позицию. Вообще, непонятно, что вы хотите сделать, но наверняка есть способ проще. Как вы хотите - так не делают )

Comment: Хочу программно кликнуть, типа adapter.onItemClick(null, 0); Но вылетает приложение сразу..

Comment: судя по имени метода, этот метод - колбэк, его не вызывают принудительно, он вызывается сам по наступлению события (в данном случае при событии нажатия на айтем списка), но у вас нет  интерфейса, который должен его реализовать и поэтому это просто метод, который никакого клика делать не будет, но даже если бы он был правильно реализован, он все равно не "нажимает" на айтем, а извещает, что было нажатие - зависимость обратная.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745919/clicking-on-item-programmatically-in-recyclerview

Comment: Jarvis_J,перепробовал все варианты из вашей ссылки, вылетает приложение и все.. Или там надо еще в адаптере код модернизировать?

Comment: в первую очередь надо оформить соответствующе вопрос. "вылетает и все" - это пустой звук, если вылетает, приложите стектрейс и проблемный код

Comment: вот этот код работает, но непонятно время задержки 100, а если будет много items, то и 100 может не успеть сработать и вылетет приложение?  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mapsActivity.mUi.gallery_rv.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(0).itemView.performClick();

                            }
                        },100);